# Output a minified version and non minified version with Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I have this bundler in Gulpfile.js, it works well:

```js
var compile = (watch) => {
  var bundler = watchify(browserify('./src/index.js', { debug: true }).transform(babel));

  var rebundle = () => {
    bundler.bundle()
      .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
      .pipe(source('lib.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
  };

  if (watch) {
    bundler.on('update', function() {
      console.log('-> bundling...');
      rebundle();
    });
  }

  rebundle();
};
```

this gives me: arli.js and arli.js.map

but when trying to uglify it like so:

```js
var compile = (watch) => {
  var bundler = watchify(browserify('./src/index.js', { debug: true }).transform(babel));

  var rebundle = () => {
    bundler.bundle()
      .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
      .pipe(source(lib.js))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

    return gulp.src('./dist/lib.js')
      .pipe(rename('lib.min.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(uglify({
        preserveComments: 'license',
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
  };

  if (watch) {
    bundler.on('update', function() {
      console.log('-> bundling...');
      rebundle();
    });
  }

  rebundle();
};
```

this give me the same two files, but if i repeat the task it will give me lib.min.js and lib.min.js.map too, because in the first time the lib.js wasn't existed.

i tried with run-sequence but it's the same too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to use the `end` callback?

```
var compile = (watch, done) => {
  var bundler = watchify(browserify('./src/index.js', { debug: true }).transform(babel));

  var rebundle = () => {
    bundler.bundle()
      .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
      .pipe(source(lib.js))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/')).on('end', function () {
        gulp.src('./dist/lib.js')
          .pipe(rename('lib.min.js'))
          .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
          .pipe(uglify({
            preserveComments: 'license',
          }))
          .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/')).on('end', function() {
            done();
          });
      });
  };

  if (watch) {
    bundler.on('update', function() {
      console.log('-> bundling...');
      rebundle();
    });
  }

  rebundle();
};
```